# Determine the class hierarchy of a class

Tags: java, reflection

My only concern with the following class is the line `hierarchy.trimToSize()` in `determineHierarchy`, because it is not necessary for determining the class hierarchy. However, putting it in the constructor clutters the code more than my current solution. Any recommendations or should I just live with it?

Since this class is completely finished and tested, I also look for any other helpful comments. The target version is 1.8.

```
/** The class hierarchy of a class. */
public class ClassHierarchy {

    private final List<Class<?>> hierarchy;

    /**
     * Creates a ClassHierarchy instance for the given class {@literal clazz}.
     * 
     * @param clazz
     *            Class for which the class hierarchy should be determined. Must not be null and must refer to a class
     *            type.
     * 
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             if {@literal clazz} does not refer to a class type
     * @throws NullPointerException
     *             if {@literal clazz} is null
     */
    public ClassHierarchy(Class<?> clazz) {
        validateConstructorArgument(clazz);
        hierarchy = Collections.unmodifiableList(determineHierarchy(clazz));
    }

    /**
     * Returns the class hierarchy as an immutable list.
     * 
     * <p>
     * The classes are ordered, starting with the class for which the instance was created and ending with
     * {@code Object.class}.
     * 
     * @return the class hierarchy as an immutable list.
     */
    public List<Class<?>> getHierarchy() {
        return hierarchy;
    }

    private static void validateConstructorArgument(Class<?> clazz) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(clazz, "clazz must not be null");

        if (clazz.isEnum() || clazz.isAnnotation() || clazz.isInterface() || clazz.isArray() || clazz.isPrimitive()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("clazz must refer to a class type");
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<Class<?>> determineHierarchy(Class<?> clazz) {
        ArrayList<Class<?>> hierarchy = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Class<?> currentClass = clazz; currentClass != null; currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass()) {
            hierarchy.add(currentClass);
        }
        hierarchy.trimToSize();
        return hierarchy;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The one comment I have is that I find your `if` statement to be really hard to read:

```
if (clazz.isEnum() || clazz.isAnnotation() || clazz.isInterface() || clazz.isArray() || clazz.isPrimitive())
```

I would at least put that into a small helper to throw that exception:

```
private void checkClassRefersToClassType()
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that there is a method for every case except for proper classes. So I could implement it myself (`isProperClass`). I still would throw the exception in `validateConstructorArgument` though.

Comment: I agree, I dont see a nice way for this check; but I think having it in its own method makes it "sense" more clear.

Comment: Isn't it already pretty much in its' own method?

Comment: @SimonForsberg When you follow "clean code" to the extreme as taught by Robert Martin, you could either move the whole if thing into a method, or at least put the 4 conditions into some `doesClassReferToClassType()` helper.

Comment: Yeah, a boolean method that returns `clazz.isEnum() || clazz.isAnnotation() || clazz.isInterface() || clazz.isArray() || clazz.isPrimitive()` would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

Your class breaks [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) combining doing real work with result caching in `hierarchy` variable.

Why do you know you need caching at all? It looks like [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize) here.

I would remove this variable at all and move the call of `determineHierarchy` inside of `getHierarchy`.

Comment: If I remove the variable, I no longer need instances of that class, every method could be static and I would want to come up with a different name for it.

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer Disagree. Object of your class is hierarchy representation for specific class. You may have different hierarchies for different classes at the same time.

Comment: If hierarchy representaiton is the object of the class (which it is), I need a variable to hold the hierarchy. I would then have to move the code determining that hierarchy outside (e.g. a `ClassHierarchyFactory`) which would only consist of static methods. That might be a way to go.

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer In reality you don't need any variables. Think about your `ClassHierarchy` as a view to your `clazz`. Only one thing is impotent - API of your `ClassHierarchy`. If you `getHierarchy` will be called thousand times per seconds and on a base of profiler result you'll decide it's a bottleneck, only after this it's needed to do some caching.

Comment: @PhilippMatthiasSchäfer and don't use `static` methods without really _significant_ reason. Read this first http://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Comment: As your link states, static methods (or utility classes) are evil **if** you want your code to be purely object oriented. I actually miss the ability to write parts of a program in procedurla or functional style, if they lend themselves to be written that way, without having to wrap it in classes, when writing Java.

Answer (score 0):

> My only concern with the following class is the line hierarchy.trimToSize() in determineHierarchy

You could replace the `ArrayList` through a `LinkedList`. While the `ArrayList` reserves space, the `LinkedList` stores only what it owns. Additionally I would change the `for-loop` to a (in this case) more readable `while-loop`.

```java
private static List<Class<?>> determineHierarchy(Class<?> clazz) {
  List<Class<?>> hierarchy = new LinkedList<>();

  Class<?> currentClass = clazz;
  while (currentClass != null) {
    hierarchy.add(currentClass);
    currentClass = currentClass.getSuperclass();
  }

  return hierarchy;
}
```

> However, putting it in the constructor clutters the code more than my current solution

For that I would create a public *static factory method*. This method contains all the validation logic while the *constructor* can be private and dump.

```java
private ClassHierarchy(List<Class<?>> clazz) {
  hierarchy = clazz;
}

public static ClassHierarchy of(Class<?> clazz) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(clazz, "clazz must not be null");

  if (isProperClass(clazz))
    return new ClassHierarchy(determineHierarchy(clazz));

  throw new IllegalArgumentException("clazz must refer to a class type");
}
```

> Any recommendations or should I just live with it?

As already mentioned a method for the validation would be a nice to have.
Maybe it could like:

```java
private static boolean isProperClass(Class<?> clazz) {
  return Stream.of(clazz)
               .filter(Class::isEnum)
               .filter(Class::isAnnotation)
               .filter(Class::isInterface)
               .noneMatch(Class::isPrimitive);
}
```